# Filtering out only the highest number from a COUNT()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to display a list of bands, their singers, album name and the corresponding number of songs in that particular album.

So if Band A has released 5 albums, I need to select (from the 5 albums) their album with the most number of songs. I've 43 bands so I'm assuming (though I may be wrong) that I should be have 43 rows returned.

The following SQL prints the band's albums and the number of the songs for the corresponding album.

```
SELECT BAND.NAME AS Band_Name,
                MEMBER.NAME AS Singer_Name,
                RELEASE.TITLE AS Album_Name,
                THESONGS.SONG_NUMBER AS Song_Num
FROM RELEASE, MEMBER, MEMBEROF, BAND,
  ( SELECT ALLSONGS.RID,
           ALLSONGS.NUM AS Song_Number
   FROM
     ( SELECT RELEASE.RID AS RID,
              count(SONG.TITLE)AS NUM
      FROM RELEASE, SONG
      WHERE RELEASE.RID = SONG.RID
      GROUP BY RELEASE.RID
      ORDER BY COUNT(RELEASE.Title) DESC 
     ) ALLSONGS 
   ) THESONGS
WHERE RELEASE.RID = THESONGS.RID
  AND RELEASE.BID = BAND.BID    
  AND MEMBER.MID = MEMBEROF.MID
  AND MEMBEROF.BID = BAND.BID
  AND MEMBEROF.INSTRUMENT = 'vocals'
ORDER BY BAND.NAME
```

I'm trying to use `MAX()`on `ALLSONGS.NUM` to obtain only the highest number of songs in that band's album, but am getting the following error:

> "column "allsongs.rid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used
>   in an aggregate function"

**Note**: I can only use SQL99 standard, and cannot use SQL procedures such as `IF..ELSE`, `COALESCE`, etc.

Comment: I don't know about `COALESCE()`, but `IF` was present in the '99 standard (or before).  Why are you limited to SQL 3?  PostgreSQL has features that came _after_ that (like windowing functions, which would make this easier)...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse This is part of an assignment I'm working on, and the constraints have been set on us to disallow the use of non-standard SQL.

Comment: .... Somebody needs to have their list of "standard" checked, because `COALESCE()` _is_ considered part of the standard (over `IFNULL()`, usually).  Regardless, no RDBMS is in complete compliance with any of the standards, although modern ones have equivalent/similar functionality through 2008 (some 2011).  At the moment, I've got a way to get the information, but if a band has two albums with the same number of tracks, you get both; SQL does really well at getting multiple rows (at getting "all data matching these conditions"), not single ones...  This is nasty, what level is this class?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse It's an undergraduate assignment. I believe the lesson behind such a constraint is to pave for easier portability between varying RDBMS. Anyway, a cursory look at the dataset shows that there are albums belonging to a band with the same number of tracks. I don't suppose your way will work given the circumstance.